# How do I extract the 2nd element from a vector of pairs?

Tags: c++, stl

This is a beginner question - I have not worked much with C++'s standard library.

I have a vector that contains pairs of elements that I created used `make_pair`. Next, I sorted the elements in the vector. Now, I would like to extract the second element from each pair stored in the vector. I know I can use the `for_each` function in the standard library, but that only allows you to specify a lambda function. *How do I extract the second element so that I can put that into a separate OpenCV Mat?* Please help :)

**EDIT** 
I wrote a small `for_each` function which takes in the vector to sort, iterates over the vector for each pair, and outputs to `cmd` the elements in each pair. Instead, I want to iterate using a `for`-loop over the vector, extract each pair, and extract the second element. :)

```
typedef std::pair<float, int> value;

vector2Sort.push_back( std::make_pair(Matches.col(c).at<float>(r),r) );

std::sort(vector2Sort.begin(), vector2Sort.end(),
    [&](const value& v1, const value& v2)
      {
        return v1.first < v2.first;
      });

std::for_each(vector2Sort.begin(),
    vector2Sort.end(),[&](const vector2Sort& v)
{
 // TODO: put second element in OpenCV Mat
 // display output
 std::cout << v.second << ": " << static_cast<int>(v.first) << std::endl;
});
```

Comment: What does "extract" mean? The elements are right there, do with them as you please.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "extract", but to get the second element, it's exactly what it sounds like: `v.second`.

Comment: `for_each` is a function, not a class.

Comment: @chris Sorry, my bad. I'll edit. 
I edited my question also. I would like to put the second element in a separate OpenCV Mat. However, for_each does not allow me to do that because it expects a lambda function again.

Comment: This doesn't _look_ like a c++ beginner question.

Comment: @Eagle, The element it gives the function is the pair, which contains both the first and second element, and provides an interface to get either element.

Comment: @chris I edited it again. I added the lambda function I wrote. This just extracts the value for the second element in the pair for the vector. Instead, I would like to iterate using a for-loop over each element in the vector and extract the second element from each pair in the vector.

Comment: Given your most recent edit, have you **tried** to put the second element in an OpenCV Mat?

Comment: @DrewDormann The one that is currently displayed my recent edit. No, I haven't tried to put it in an OpenCV mat. For an OpenCV mat which is MxN, I extract each col in the mat, take the (row-value and index) pair and put it in a vector2sort, and sort the vector containing the pairs. Now, I want to extract the second element from each pair. :)

Comment: I see an OpenCV mat and a vector, but where is the *unanswered* question ?

Comment: @Eagle: `v.second` does extract the second element, I don't see a question here.

Comment: @BenjaminBannier I would like to do it using a for-loop. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you could extract the second elements with:

```
template<class T1, class T2>
static void extract_second(const vector<pair<T1, T2> >& v, vector<T2>& v2) {
    v2.resize(v.size());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        v2[i] = v[i].second;
    }
}
```

If you want to do something with the second elements inside the lambda using values outside the lambda, since you captured everything in the context by reference with `[&]`, you could e.g. do:

```
vector<float> snds;
std::for_each(vector2Sort.begin(),
    vector2Sort.end(),[&](const vector2Sort& v)
{
   snds.push_back(v.second);
   // display output
   std::cout << v.second << ": " << static_cast<int>(v.first) << std::endl;
});
```

Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Ah, shoot. I didn't think of putting it the way you did using the for-loop. I see how I can do it now. Thanks! :)

Comment: np. BTW, in the `sort` line, you could omit the custom-defined compare operator, because std::pair<T1,T2> compare on the first component T1 (in ascending order) by default. If you have ties in T1 for two elements, sort will compare on T2.

Comment: Using transform seems like a more appropriate tool fo this particular job: `std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), std::back_inserter(dst), [](auto p) { return p.second; });`

Comment: Yes, that's more STL.